# vb.net key combination

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to capture two key presses in my VB.net application, for this example CTRL + B, the code below doesn't work but it does for single keys. I have tried setting keypreview as true but this has no effect.

```
  Private Sub main_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles mybase.KeyDown
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.ControlKey And e.KeyCode = Keys.B Then
                MsgBox("CTRL + B Pressed !")
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Control key is a Modifier key. This code tests for Ctrl + B

```
e.KeyCode = Keys.B AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control
```

The key-code is B, but the modifier is Ctrl.

Your code snippet, updated:

```
Private Sub main_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles mybase.KeyDown
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.B AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control) Then
        MsgBox("CTRL + B Pressed !")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, thought it would be something simple ! Thanks :)

Comment: Just a side note, as this was not working for me... (this may be obvious) but "KeyPreview" needs to be true for the form. This answers was my fix though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add controlkey also after modifier to make it work properly.

```
Private Sub main_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
  System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles mybase.KeyDown
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.B AndAlso e.Modifiers.ControlKey = Keys.Control) Then
        MsgBox("CTRL + B Pressed !")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation for KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx), you'll note that the class exposes properties for ALT, CTRL and Modifiers which allow you to determine whether these keys were pressed in addition to the main symbol key you're interested in.

```
Private Sub main_KeyDown(
        ByVal sender As Object, 
        ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) 
   Handles mybase.KeyDown

    If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.B Then
        MsgBox("CTRL + B Pressed !")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
If e.Control = True And e.KeyCode = Keys.B Then
            'Do Something...
        End If
```