# how to disable esc key in a form?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress-windows-ui

i have a flyout as a login form, but whenever i presses the esc key the flyout will exit and i  dont want that kind of thing so is there anyway to trap that esc key thingy in flyouts ? i did test this stuff but not of them works.

```
 Private Sub ItemAdd_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    If login = True Then
        MsgBox("haha")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ItemAdd_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If login = True Then
        MsgBox("haha")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ItemAdd_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
        MsgBox("haha")

    End If
End Sub
```

OR HOW CAN I DISABLE THE ESC KEY in a FORM ?

Comment: There are tons of examples for doing this around SOE.
(ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442805/vb-net-key-combination?rq=1)   In your code example it looks like you're already pretty close.  Be sure you're forms KeyPreview property is set to true.

Comment: hmmm..tnx for the reply..i try that out..tnx

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but you give it a try:

```
Private Sub ItemAdd_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
    e.Handled = True
  End If

End Sub
```