# Key combination in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Can any one help me to read multiple key strokes in VB.NET.for Example, I want to read Control+P+H key combinations.I tried something like the code below but didn't work...
In form Keydown

```
if e.control=true and e.keycode=keys.P and e.keycode=keys.H then
end if
```

Comment: There is no simple way to detect that more than one non-modifier key is depressed at a time.  Why do you want to do such a thing? I'll wager that there's a better solution to the problem you're actually trying to solve.  If I'm wrong then it would involve handling multiple events and determining that they are raised in a particular sequence or else making multiple API calls.

Comment: The control key is a modifier key. Please see example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442805/vb-net-key-combination

Answer (score 3):

Ok after reading your post and from what I can understand, something like this should do the trick.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim keyCombo As New List(Of Keys)({Keys.ControlKey, Keys.H, Keys.P})
Dim currentKeys As New List(Of Keys)

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    currentKeys.Add(e.KeyCode)

    If currentKeys.Intersect(keyCombo).Count = keyCombo.Count Then
        MessageBox.Show("CTRL + H + P Has Been Pressed....")
        currentKeys.Clear()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    currentKeys.Remove(e.KeyCode)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

End Class
```

If you have any questions, let me know and I will try my best to answer them, however this should get you well and truly on your way :)

Comment: Well this was a very special solution, I've never seen anything like this before. Nice!

Comment: @VisualVincent Cheers :) I used this all the time over the regular `if e.keycode = `

Comment: I mostly override the `ProcessCmdKey` function to handle key combinations. I don't know why but I like it more than the standard `KeyDown/KeyPress/KeyUp` events.

Comment: that's the way :), Ill have to take a look at it