# Check if a sequence of keys are pressed in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, sequence, keypress

Im not sure if this is possible but I am working on a small project where I would like to be able to enter in a specific sequence of keys and then something happens. Its purpose is to act as a sort of "password" to unlock additional functionality. Im thinking maybe I could store key presses in an array somehow and compare the array to another that has the same key presses in it already or something similar but im not sure on where to start.

Comment: Please share more info about your program. Are you doing a winforms or wpf app? Do you want to track a textbox, whole form or some other control?

Comment: Its in a windows form using visual studio 2017. Ideally id like to be able to track the key strokes across the whole form.

Comment: This is to unlock some admin type functionality? If so, I wouldn't capture global key strokes, it's unnecessary code that would be running all the time. I would just add something specific to a control somewhere. For example, I have an app that unlocks additional functionality if you type a specific set of characters in the search box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Key combination in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136859/key-combination-in-vb-net)